# Repopulate old select input

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a clients table and one of the fields is office.  This value can be London or Paris.  Within my controller I pass the view the options

```
public function edit(Client $client)
{
    $office = array('London' => 'London', 'Paris' => 'Paris');
    return view('clients.edit', compact('client', 'office'));
}
```

Now within my view I am doing

```
@foreach($office as $off)
    <option value="{{ $client->office }}">{{ $client->office }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Now `$client->office` is the previously selected value.  So say Paris is saved in the database for the client, the selected option should be Paris and the unselected option should be London.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is `$office = array('London' => 'London', 'Paris' => 'Paris');`

You can try

```
@foreach($office as $key => $value)
   <option value="{{ $value }}" @if($value == $client->office) selected @endif>{{ $key }}</option>
@endforeach
```